# Conga Composer: set default parameters on layout of tool

Tags: attachment, parameters, conga, defaults

My question can be trivial but I'm struggling with following problem:
when I open Conga Composer tool, I have few options to choose:

[image]

My goal is to set "Enable" as default to Save a Copy in Notes & Attachments to prevent user from setting it everytime the document is generated. I was thinking about adding parameters to Conga Solution "&SC0=1&SC1=Attachments" ([documentation here](https://support.conga.com/content/composer/composer-parameter-guide/sc1)) but it doesn't seem to work.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Have you checked with Conga support?